# What causes Apache to invoke an executable on the server?

Tags: html, apache, http

I have an executable on the server that is suppose to be invoked by the browser but the browser downloads it instead as a binary file to the **"Downloads"** directory .

The index.html has:

```
 <head>
     <title></title>
     <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=admin/launch?script=rhtemplate=login">
 </head>
```

How does "launch"  get started ?

```
ScriptAlias /admin/ "/opt/tms/lib/web/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/opt/tms/lib/web/cgi-bin">
     Options +ExecCGI
     AllowOverride None
    Options None
     Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This use to work in httpd 2.0 ; we updated to 2.2

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that need to be set.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html

you could put your executable in a ScriptAliased directory.  default apache configs normally have /cgi-bin/ as a ScriptAlias.  So if you move your script to there it should Just work.

```
ScriptAlias "/scripts/" "/usr/local/apache2/scripts/"
```

can be used to set up different directory, or to create one if your default doesn't include it.

Or if you want to allow execution outside of ScriptAlias directories, you can set `Options +ExecCGI`  in the directory and then tell Apache what should be treated as a script.

Enable  cgi execution in that directory.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/admin">
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Then you would need to tell Apache what extensions should be treated as cgi using a handler

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

so you would need to rename your script to something like `launch.cgi`

-- from new info --

```
<Directory "/opt/tms/lib/web/cgi-bin">
     Options +ExecCGI
     AllowOverride None
    Options None
     Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

you have `Options none` and `Options +ExecCGI`  in that stanza,  remove the `Options none`, and see if that makes a difference..

Comment: Hello   Thank you for the feedback ,    
     ScriptAlias /admin/ "/opt/tms/lib/web/cgi-bin/"

    <Directory "/opt/tms/lib/web/cgi-bin">
         Options +ExecCGI
         AllowOverride None
        Options None
         Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

Comment: Is launch executable by the user Apache runs as.  And do you have the cgi module loaded